# iPhone Bluetooth Audio API

Tags: iphone, bluetooth

My car has bluetooth capabilities for connecting to my iphone for phone calls; however, it does NOT support bluetooth audio for music streaming. I know apps like viber or skype also use bluetooth for phone calls. My question is: is it possible to write an app that fakes phone calls to stream music to my car, as if someone is calling me (but is actually playing music)? Is there some other way to hack this to get bluetooth audio streaming?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First poster -
There is already an app to do this - it's part of SBSettings called Bluetooth Mono that needs to be installed (so only MONO and only for JB'd phones).

Second poster - 
I suspect you are correct about HSP - I've installed the app and the sound quality is terrible.

So, I've put all my music on a USB stick and leave it permanently plugged in. Far superior sound.

Mike

Answer (score 1):

No need to jailbreak your phone. Just buy the A2DPblocker app. Costs $2.99. Sound quality isn't perfect but better than the alternative. Worked for my 2010 Volkswagen so should work for any other car that supports bluetooth but not streaming music.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's an easy way to do this.  But the bigger issue is that it would sound terrible.  The bluetooth connections for doing phone calls use headset profile (HSP) and are low bitrate, mono, and frequency limited to voice ranges.

Applications for streaming audio/music over bluetooth use A2DP profile, which is much higher bandwidth and stereo.

If you try to pipe music over a an HSP phone link it will sound horrible, just as it does if you are talking to someone on the phone and they have music playing in the background.